# Is there a way to see more than the top 20 active pages on google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

It would be beneficial to be able to see more than the top 20 active pages on Google Analytics. Perhaps by a URL hack or something?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a URL hack. However, there is a [Google Analytics Real-time API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/) that you could use and that would give you access to metics like pagepath, pagetitle; however, it is in private beta and you'll have to request access via [Real Time Report API Private Beta form.](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1qfRFysCikpgCMGqgF3yXdUyQW4xAlLyjKuOoOEFN2Uw/viewform)